# How to handle in python a string variable for sql query that can contain both " and '?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, mariadb

I form an sql query

```
query_ = f'NSERT INTO {entity} (id, link, name, country_id) SELECT  {key}, "{value}", "{row[0]}", id FROM countries WHERE name = "{row[1]}";'
```

row = [] is list of lists with two strings

at some point I get row[0] = 'Someword "somename"'

and my variable turns into:

```
query_ = f'NSERT INTO wineries (id, link, name, country_id) SELECT  30052, "someword-somename", "Someword "somename"", id FROM countries WHERE name = "France";'
```

an i get error `mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

I cheerfully change the query formula to:

```
query_ = f"INSERT INTO {entity} (id, link, name, country_id) SELECT  {key}, '{value}', '{row[0]}', id FROM countries WHERE name = '{row[1]}';"
```

and next time get row[0] = Château La Chouette d'Or
and I get the error again

First idea make something like that:

```
try:
    query_ = f"bla-bla-bla"
    myfunction(query_)
except:
   query_ = f'bla-bla-bla'
   myfunction(query_)
```

*But maybe there is a standard, more beautiful solution for processing such strings and I invented a wheel?*

Comment: Use a prepared query instead. Then you don't need to worry about quoting at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid possible SQL injection but also substitution problems with special characters which need to be escaped, the way to go is to substitute the parameters when executing the statement:

```
# Only numbers and literals can be substituted in execute(), 
# so we need to substitute table name before:
query_ = f'INSERT INTO {entity} (id, link, name, country_id) SELECT  ?, ?, ?, id FROM countries WHERE name = ?'

parameters= (key, value, row[0], row[1])
try:
    cursor.execute(query_, parameters)
except ...: 
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I knew about parametric query, about passing parameters by tuple, but I didn't know that it is possible to pass it into SELECT too

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **Python3+** use **"""**.

**Example:-**

```
"""your string with " and ' both"""

str_var = f"""random text {2+2} with 'test' and "dummy" as well"""
```

By wrapping you string with """ you can use any charecters(symbols) in a string.

Comment: I try both:
query_ = f'''INSERT..........'''
and 
query_ = f"""INSERT.........."""
an have the same error :
mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

Comment: No, absolutely not.  This is an improper way to handle SQL queries and leaves the query open for SQL injection. A parameterised query should be used.